# Managing user access to files

Tags: perl, file, security

I'm looking for some guidance on the best way to manage user-level access to files (ideally with Perl, but any general guidance also appreciated). Here is the requirement:

- I have users upload files which I want to keep secure so that no one can generally see them apart from the owner that uploaded them
- I want to then be able to grant access to other specific users so that they can open the files read-only
- All my users are managed in a MySQL database
- I intend to hold the uploaded files in the file system, not the database. I will store metadata about the files in the database.

What's the best approach to manage secure access by user to the files? I can rename the files on upload and keep in a secure directory somewhere. I can store the required access information in the database by user. But how to manage access for any given user? Copy the files out to a temporary area while accessing them?

Comment: I'm afraid this questions is a bit too broad to meaningfully answer. You can do this - of course you can - but the devil is in the details.

Comment: To clarify, specific users should only have access to specific files. Each user would have their own list of allowed files for access. All other files would not be visible or accessible to the user. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It does, but it's still not something that can be trivially answered. Stack Overflow is really about helping programmers figure out problems. Not about writing solutions from scratch. If you're trying this and you're having a problem with it - this would be a good place to ask about it.

Comment: Well I've searched for the best approach to this and can find nothing of much value. My reasoning is there is no point in me heading off in the wrong direction on this and wasting hours putting something together that makes no sense. Hence my 'general' question looking for some general guidance, references etc I can read. I'm not looking for coding problem advice at this time. More for guidance on the best approach for user-level file access management, especially with Perl.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around and talking to a programmer friend (who was helpful enough to say more than "it's not trivial"), I got the steer needed on this question. In case it may help someone in the future, here is the synopsis:

- upload the files to a secure area (users cannot access directly)
- hold the meta data in the database (eg. who has access to what files)

When accessing:

- check the user has access according to the database
- use Perl module File::Type to determine mime type
- use Perl module IO::File to open a file and print it using the appropriate mime type header to the user's browser

Check the CPAN library for the details of each module.

Works very nicely!
And actually quite trivial :)